# GoDaddy .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've develop a site in my computer using xampp and flight php and everything works just fine. I decided to upload it in godaddy using windows plesk account and when I try to access my site, it produces 404 error. I know the index.php was executed but the rewrite is not working. Ex. when I access mysite.com/login, it produces 404 error. I used the default flight php htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /httpdocs/uem-um-gov.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is the path for this .htaccess and what is your `DocumentRoot` path?

Comment: Godaddy support has this about 'htaccess' : [help/article/2504/what-is-htaccess](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2504/what-is-htaccess?countrysite=uk)

Comment: @anubhava The Document root was in httpdocs/mysite. And the .htaccess is located in mysite directory.

Comment: ok then comment out `RewriteBase` line and retest

Comment: @anubhava Tried it but no effect. I found out that the .htaccess file has no effect at all. Maybe because I'm on windows platform? Is there other way to rewrite url?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that the server is using IIS and not apache, so I replaced my .htaccess with the Web.config equivalent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was very confused and spending way too much time trying to get a .htaccess file to work.